# How to connect to Telegram using telethon without entering your phone (or bot token)?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have written the following script that listens for new messages on telegram public channels. Problem is that every time the script is used on a new machine telegram is sending a code to the phone number linked to the dev account. You have to enter this code to authorize the new machine. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
import configparser
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (
PeerChannel
)

api_id = 'xxxxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Here you define the target channel that you want to listen to:
input_channels = ('https://t.me/xxxxxx','https://t.me/xxxx','https://t.me/xxxxxxx')

print(input_channels)

#create a client
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

# Listen to messages from target channel 
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=input_channels)) 
async def newMessageListener(event):
    # Get message text 
    newMessage = event.message.message 

    print(newMessage)


with client: 
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Telegram introduced those security measures to protect both users and their own servers. Imagine someone getting their hands on your code and spamming someone - it's for your good. So the question: why are you so frequently moving machines?

Comment: @h4z3 I am basically building a desktop app where a user could get updates about new  posts on telegram public channels he is interested in. Somehow he needs to get the code that comes to my phone (dev account is linked to my phone number).

Comment: That's not correct usage of your api token - never give your api token to someone else, they may use it to do something against ToS or even illegal and it would be all from your account! User should use their own api token for such stuff.